# A question on the fiber class of a fibration.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be compact complex manifold and $\phi:X\rightarrow C$ be a holomorphic map to a smooth curve $C$. Denote the general fiber of $\phi$ by $Y$. How can one see that $Y|_Y$ is a torsion divisor?

Answer (score 2):

Let $t$ be a point of $C$. Then in an open neighborhood $V$ of $t$, $t$ is a principal divisor, so $Y$ is a principal divisor in $\phi^{-1}(V)$. Therefore $Y|_Y$ is the trivial divisor (viewed as a line bundle) on $Y$.